# How to check a callback is pending?

Tags: javascript

I am studying JavaScript and have the task to write a public function to check whether an asynchronous call was made, but the response is still pending (i.e. the process is "running"). It needs to return `true` if the process is ongoing or `false` if it's not.

```
function Machine() {
  function onReady() {
    alert( 'ready!' );
  }
  this.setOnReady = function(newOnReady) {
    onReady = newOnReady;
  };
  this.run = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      onReady();
    }, 10000);
  };
}

 var machine = new Machine();
 alert('before the run: ' + machine.isRunning()); // before: false
 machine.run();
 alert('is running: ' + machine.isRunning()); // is running: true
 machine.setOnReady(function() {
     alert("after: " + machine.isRunning()); // after: false
 });
```

Comment: Excuse me sir, but my formatting and question was more clearly for me and I think for people from Eastern Europe, who do not speak in English much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could code it:

```js
function Machine() {
  // add this private variable
  var isRunning = false;
  function onReady() {
    alert( 'ready!' );
  }
  this.setOnReady = function(newOnReady) {
    onReady = newOnReady;
  };
  this.run = function() {
    isRunning = true; // set flag
    setTimeout(function() {
      isRunning = false; //clear flag
      onReady();
    }, 2000); // 2 seconds, I don't have patience!
  };
  // Add this method:
  this.isRunning = function() {
    return isRunning;
  }
}

var machine = new Machine();
console.log('before the run: ' + machine.isRunning()); // before: false
machine.run();
console.log('is running: ' + machine.isRunning()); // is running: true
machine.setOnReady(function() {
  console.log("after: " + machine.isRunning()); // after: false
});
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In your run(), set a flag on the object to true (via `this.running = true;`) that your isRunning() method returns.

After finishing the run, set it back to false.

Comment: I did not understand you much, but your answer pushed me to this :        `function Machine() {
      var running = false;
    function onReady() {
    alert( 'ready!' );
  }
  this.setOnReady = function(newOnReady) {
    onReady = newOnReady;
   };
    this.run = function() {
     running = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      onReady();
    }, 1000);
   };
    this.isRunning= function(){
   return running;
       }
     }`

Comment: Nice! That seems very similar to @trincot's answer, so feel free to accept theirs :)